# How can I use a method I defined in the current Factory?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-factory

I am have a factory I am working wirh that makes references to the methods defined inside the object returned by the factory. I these methods are all undefined when I alert them or console.log. Is there a way to reference methods defined in the same factory? To put it another way, is there a way to achieve what I illustrate below?

```
angular.module('myModule').factory('myFactory', ['$window', '$q', '$rootScope', '$http', function($window, $q, $rootScope, $http) {

  return {
    method1: function () {
       return 1;
    },
    {
    method2: function () {
       return this.method1 + 1;
    }
}]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i would suggest that you do it something like this.

```
angular.module('myModule').factory('myFactory', function() {
  var method1 = function(){ return 1; };
  return {
    method1: method1,
    method2: function () {
       return method1 + 1;
    }
}]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Due to javascript's function hoisting, you can write the following:

```
angular.module('myModule').factory('myFactory', ['$window', '$q', '$rootScope', '$http', function($window, $q, $rootScope, $http) {

  return {
    method1: method1,    
    method2: method2
    };

    function method1(){
        return 1;
    }

    function method2() {
        return method1() + 1;
    }

}]);
```

This is the pattern I like to use as it keeps it really clear which are publicly exposed functions and what is just internal detail.

For example, you can have a 'private' function used by the others, but will not be exposed by the service. Very handy.

```
angular.module('myModule').factory('myFactory', ['$window', '$q', '$rootScope', '$http', function($window, $q, $rootScope, $http) {

  return {
    method1: method1,    
    method2: method2
    };

    function method1(){
        return 1 + privateMethod1();
    }

    function method2() {
        return method1() + 1;
    }

    // Not returned by service, so private.
    function privateMethod1() {
        return 3;
    }
}]);
```

A good and thorough article can be found at http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html which hopefully gives you some further insight.